# c pointer issue with random garbage

Tags: c, coap

I had written one coap client with libcoap to communicate with leshan server
The issue is whenever I did a PUT request, first time it is correct, but if I do a PUT request from leshan, say 12345678 is the payload it adds a garbled value after that.
Also if my next payload is longer, it behaves correctly and no garbled value is padded.
if I again reduce payload size, the older size retains and garbled value padded to payload.
code snippet of coap client:

```
  unsigned char *data;
  memset (data, '\0', sizeof(data));
  coap_get_data(request, &size, &data);
```

`coap_get_data` getting data from server

I entered payload in leshan server as `sdsdsdsdasasasast`

But the client received  : `sdsdsdsdasasasast�`

And wireshark says : `sdsdsdsdasasasast\201\005`

I always did a memset before inserting data into arrays, still I don't know where it got such things padded  after payload

Comment: `unsigned char *data;` – where do you expect `data` to point to if you didn't initialize it?

Comment: You need to allocate some memory for `data` - `malloc` perhaps?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant already did, forgot to mention here :
  data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*128);
    memset (data, '\0', sizeof(data));

Comment: @Zim can you guarantee that the server isn't sending you this garbage?

Comment: @Magisch, that is where I am confused too. The data WIreshark captured shows sdsdsdsdasasasast\201\005 although in leshan it displayed that as sdsdsdsdasasasast�
hence \201\005 which was not part of payload is added and showed in leshan as �

Comment: @Zim In that case your problem is most likely with the server code sending stuff rather than with what you posted. Ignoring the memory allocation issues (which you commented you fixed) your problem is then outside of the scope of the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
memset (data, '\0', sizeof(data));
```

where `data` does not point to any valid memory, actually invokes undefined behavior.

Before *copying into* (or even reading from) a memory location pointed by a pointer, you need to make sure that the pointer points to a valid memory location allocated for that particular process.

Either use a compiler allocated memory, like

```
 unsigned char data[256] = {0};
```

or use `malloc()` or family to get the memory allocated to the pointer. Don't forget to free it afterwards,tho.

Comment: already did but the result is same.